# Capture pixels underneath a window using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, capture, pixel

Is there a way to capture pixels underneath a QWidget/QDialog/QMainWindow while it's visible?

I thought this code would do the trick, but it includes the window in the capture.

```
QPixmap pix = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->screen->grabWindow(0, myGeometry.x(), myGeometry.y(), myGeometry.width(), myGeometry.height());
```

I need to screenshot everytime the window moves, so it needs to be very fast.

Comment: Apparently you are looking for [`QWidget::grab()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab) method, it'll capture the contents of the widget/window without including the window border and you can capture a specific rectangle or the entire widget.

Comment: I think you can't capture invisible pixels using Qt. However you can hide your window while capturing or make part of it transparent and capture that part. I'm curious, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to create an iOS/OSX-like translucency effect (ie: transparency+blur). To do so, I'm capturing what's behind the window, blurring it using a Gaussian blur and setting the result as the QWidget/QDialog/whatever's background using QPainter. At first paintEvent call, the window has not been displayed yes, so the effect is achieved and very beautiful. But following screenshots are messed up because they contain the window that's been displayed :'( So I need to access what's underneath the window at any moment.

Comment: Here's an example of what it does at first paintEvent call: http://i58.tinypic.com/23jgw8n.png

Comment: Wow, that looks awesome! I would love to see your code :) .. but sorry I have no solution to the problem